# html css numbered list not working correct

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item !important;
}

li {
  display: block !important;
}

li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " " !important;
  counter-increment: item !important;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second
    <ol>
      <li>Second Dot One</li>
      <li>Second Dot Two</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>

<p>test sentence.</p>

<ol start="12">
  <li>&nbsp;It must start from 12 not 1</li>
</ol>
```

Why it doesn't starts from 12? JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7kueakxb/1/

Comment: It is your `counter-reset: item`.

Comment: You created your own formatting of numbers. You removed the right formatting when you applied `display: block`

Comment: I know it all. But I need solution without losing my 2.1 and 2.2

Comment: What is supposed to start from 12...what is this supposed to look like....?

Comment: I feel like someone needs to say this. You can't have *everything* in your CSS be !important, or else nothing is actually important. If you have to use !important in your CSS, you have a problem somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The following style sheet numbers nested list items as "1", "1.1", "1.1.1", etc.

EXAMPLE

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item
}

li {
  display: block
}

li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>li element
    <ol>
      <li>sub li element</li>
      <li>sub li element</li>
      <li>sub li element</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>li element</li>
  <li>li element
    <ol>
      <li>sub li element</li>
      <li>sub li element</li>
      <li>sub li element</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Lol, thats a funny anwser. That doens't solve the actual problem, as he want to keep the numbering with `1.1`, `1.2`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this line of CSS:

```
li {
  display: block !important;
}
```

The reason is that the above CSS will change these `li`s `display` from `list-item` to `block`. So the default behavior is removed.

Comment: Without this part it don't work correctly. Simply I need to make it start 12

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: To keep my 2.1 and 2.2 sections.

Then start anther ol starts from 12.

And I don't want to use div tags

Comment: Can you update your question to include these requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS was conflict, please try this:

```css
.first_ol ol {
    counter-reset: item !important;
}

.first_ol li {
    display: block !important;
}

.first_ol li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") " " !important;
    counter-increment: item !important;
}
```

```html
    <div class="first_ol">
    <ol>
        <li>First</li>
        <li>Second
            <ol>
                <li>Second Dot One</li>
                <li>Second Dot Two</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>

<p>test sentence.</p>

<p>test another paragraph.</p>

<ol start="12">
    <li>&nbsp;It must start from 12 not 1</li>
    <li>&nbsp;It must start from 12 not 1</li>
    <li>&nbsp;It must start from 12 not 1</li>
    <li>&nbsp;It must start from 12 not 1</li>
    <li>&nbsp;It must start from 12 not 1</li>
    <li>&nbsp;It must start from 12 not 1</li>
    <li>&nbsp;It must start from 12 not 1</li>
    <li>&nbsp;It must start from 12 not 1</li>
    <li>&nbsp;It must start from 12 not 1</li>
    <li>&nbsp;It must start from 12 not 1</li>
    <li>&nbsp;It must start from 12 not 1</li>
    <li>&nbsp;It must start from 12 not 1</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `counters` have nothing to do with the default numbering behavior of the `ol`. In your code, you just remove the default behavior and add your own implementation. If you want to go with that one, I would suggest that you specifically reset the counter with CSS for the `ol` you want to change with `counter-reset`.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item !important;
}

li {
  display: block !important;
}

li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " " !important;
  counter-increment: item !important;
}
ol[start="12"] {
  counter-reset: item 11 !important;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second
    <ol>
      <li>Second Dot One</li>
      <li>Second Dot Two</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>

<ol start="12">
  <li>It must start from 12 not 1</li>
</ol>
```

You don't have to use the `[start="12"]` selector of course, you can add any class you want, and of course you'll have to add a class for every value you'd like to override.